# Do tensors need to be symmetric for the symmetric product to commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

I have proven the following Proposition without using the fact that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are symmetric:
[image]

Why is this assumption there? Why wouldn't commutativity work, if we hadn't symmetric inputs?

For example, in the proof of the first and second equation I didn't use symmetry of $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ anywhere. The first equation:

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in V$ be arbitrary. We then have
$$\begin{align*}
    (\alpha \beta) \left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right)  
    &=\operatorname{Sym}(\alpha \otimes \beta)\left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right)\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} {}^{\sigma}(\alpha \otimes \beta)(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k},v_{k+1},\ldots,v_{k+l})\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} (\alpha \otimes \beta)(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)},v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} \alpha (v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)}) \cdot \beta (v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} \beta (v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \cdot \alpha (v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} (\beta \otimes \alpha) \otimes \left(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)},v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)}\right)\\
    &\stackrel{*}{=} \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} {}^{\tau}(\beta \otimes \alpha) \otimes \left(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)},v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}\right)\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} {}^{\sigma\tau}(\beta \otimes \alpha) \otimes \left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k},v_{k+1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right)\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\eta \in S_{k+l}} {}^{\eta}(\beta \otimes \alpha) \otimes \left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k},v_{k+1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right)\\
    &=\operatorname{Sym}(\beta \otimes \alpha) = \beta \alpha
\end{align*}$$
In the step (*) we have defined a permutation $\tau(1),\ldots,\tau(k),\tau(k+1),\ldots,\tau(k+l) = l+1,\ldots,l+k,1,\ldots,l$ resulting in a new substituted permutation $\eta = \sigma \tau$ which runs over all $S_{k+l}$ as $\sigma$ does. This proves $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$ for symmetric tensors $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

The second equation:
\begin{align*}
[(a \alpha + b \beta) \gamma]  \left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right) 
&= \operatorname{Sym}((a \alpha + b \beta) \otimes \gamma)\left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} {}^{\sigma}((a \alpha + b \beta) \otimes \gamma)\left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} ((a \alpha + b \beta) \otimes \gamma)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \\
&= \frac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} (a \alpha \otimes \gamma + b \beta \otimes \gamma)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \\
&= \frac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} a (\alpha \otimes \gamma)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) + \frac{1}{(k+l)!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} b (\beta \otimes \gamma)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \\
&= a \operatorname{Sym}(\alpha \otimes \gamma)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) + b \operatorname{Sym}(\beta \otimes \gamma)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \\
&= [a (\alpha \gamma)](v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) + [b (\beta \gamma)](v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}).
\end{align*}

Comment: @M.Wind Could you point out to me which exact step in my proof was erroneous? Because it is not possible to arrive at this conclusion without symmetry, yet I did it somehow.

Comment: What about your proof of the first equation? That would be more straightforward to read and criticize. Oh, you didn’t finish. The part you did shows only the first equality of two, not the interesting one. You should not claim to have proved much. All you verified was distributivity.

Comment: @M.Wind the claim was $S(AB)=S(BA)$, not $AB=BA$.

Comment: Also, if A and B are (2,0) matrices $\textit{Sym}(AB)$ is a (4,0) tensor and the sum of 24 individual index permutations.

Comment: What book is this from?